# Deploy node js REST Api on production and fetch data using react native

Tags: node.js, api

i am new to node js. i am learning to create REST api's on node js. i create a basic file in node js and run it on my local machine it is working fine and i test it using the postman and it giving me the results as well. Here is the code

```
const express = require('express'); //for routes
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// creating an array of courses
const courses = [
    { id: 1, name: 'courses1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'courses2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'courses3' },
]

// getting specific course
app.get('/api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {
    const course = courses.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if (!course) return res.status(404).send('the course with the given id not found.');
    res.send(course);
});

// post course data 
app.post('/api/courses', (req, res) => {

    const { error } = validateinputs(req.body);

    if (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
        return;
    }

    const course = {
        id: courses.length + 1,
        name: req.body.name
    }

    courses.push(course);
    res.send(course);
});

// running on port.
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Listening on port ' + port));
```

This is the basic code i have tested on my local machine with postman and its working.
But now i want it to deploy on my server. i have installed node and npm using server console. and copy this file inside my new created project on production server. Like this.

```
const express = require('express'); //for routes

const app = express();
app.use(express.json()); // for post

// creating an array of courses
const courses = [
    {id: 1, name: 'courses1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'courses2'},
    {id: 3, name: 'courses3'},
]

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hey');
});

// res.send(courses);

// getting specific course
app.get('/api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {
    const course = courses.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id)
);

if (!course) return res.status(404).send('the course with the given id not found.');
res.send(course);

});

// running on port.
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Listening on port ' + port));
```

then i start the server manually on production server like

```
node index.js
```

and its giving me the message

```
Listening on port 3000
```

Now when i testing it with postman its not working fine. I am using this link where the project is installed under the folder adroit_api.

```
https://adroit-services.co.uk/adroit_api/api
```

It is returning me the source page of this site home page

```
https://adroit-services.co.uk
```

i do not know what to do. please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may have routing issues outside your NodeJS Express app. Check your web server's settings like virtual host.

That being said, your API runs on port 3000 whereas your web server is on port 80. So, you might want to check your API at something like `https://example.com:3000/api` as well (replace `example.com` with your own server's URL), as accessing `https://example.com/api` means you're trying to access it on port 80 instead of 3000.

Also, I can read your server-sided code if you put them inside your web server's directory by accessing `https://example.com/example_api/index.js`, which **will very likely** cause **very serious** security breach.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. i did try these 2 approaches as well. https://example.com:3000/api, https://example.com/api but its gives me the error. so no luck with these 2.

1 more thing do i need to run my server manually like i did "node index.js"

Comment: yeah i know there is a security breach there. but this is just for testing purpose i am not focusing on it right now.

Comment: I suggest that you try and make a subdomain such as `api.example.com` and then run the app there first. And also, don't forget the `https://` in front of your link when you're testing with Postman as your hosting may have assumed it as `http://` request instead and redirected you to your homepage.

Comment: when i am usign link like this https://www.adroit-services.co.uk/adroit_api/ its giving me the error 403 forbidden  You do not have permission to access this document. 

and when i am accessing this link https://www.adroit-services.co.uk/adroit_api/api its giving me the status of the 404 not found.

Comment: Thanks ionizer.aj your subdomain suggestion worked for me. i just need to know 1 thing only how to make it automate, so not to run "node index.js" every time using server terminal.